# Mp3 ID3 info in Nautilus properties window

Tags: nautilus, file-properties, id3, nautilus-extensions

In Nautilus, we have dedicated tabs for images, pdf files, etc. However, there is no such tabs for mp3 ID3 information.

[image: Nautilus Properties Window]

Is it possible to add this tab? If a plugin is needed, which plugin does provide this functionality?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Mine does show basic information about the audio file.

Comment: @navjotjsingh I'm using Nautilus 3.14.2 on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: @navjotjsingh Could you please tell me which Nautilus extensions are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to install totem or gnome-mplayer. Both provide a nautilus plugin that brings this info on the properties window in nautilus.

<sub>Credits: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173489</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There's something called MediaInfo which does this. Here's a link to the website:

https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo

To install MediaInfo, enter the terminal and paste in the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install mediainfo`

`nautilus -q && nautilus &` (this restarts nautilus).

Now you should have a tab in the properties of audio files which looks like this:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exz4r.png)

Comment: I installed that package but still there's no such tab in my Nautilus.

Comment: It worked for me, but I'm using linux mint 17. Did you completely restart nautilus?

Comment: You could try `killall nautilus` in the terminal, then launch by pressing [Alt] + [F2] and typing "nautilus".

Comment: I found a way to get this tab to show.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto How?

Comment: @KenSharp Please read [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/703243/228067).